# plug all values from a pandas dataframe column into a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a column of strings and a function that takes in a string. I would like to go through the df plugging in the values in that column without typing it, what is the best way to go about this? I looked into apply but it didn't seem applicable in this situation.

Edit:

```
df = A B     C
     1 2 "cheese"
     2 4 "spiders"

def samplefunc(item):
    print('i hate ' + item)
```

Comment: Can you add sample of data with sample function?

Comment: @jezrael just added, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
def samplefunc(item):
    print('i hate ' + item)

df.C.apply(samplefunc)
i hate cheese
i hate spiders
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 2, 'cheese'],
        [2, 4, 'spiders']
    ], columns=list('ABC'))

df.loc[:, 'C'] = df.C.apply('I hate {}'.format)

df
```

[image]